# PInvokeStackImbalance when calling a dll function from C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport, dllexport

I'm writing a WPF app that needs to call some C++ code that exists in a dll I've written. I'm always getting PInvokeStackImbalance errors, even with the the most rudimentary test functions. Eg, in the C++ dll:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Test( int foo);
```

The function does nothing. The c# side looks like this:

```
    [DllImport("myDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern void Test( int foo);
```

And I call this c# function like so:

Test(1)

... and I get a PInvokeStackImbalance!! How can this be?

Thanks in advance...

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to specify [CallingConvention.Cdecl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx). There is an example in the doc. The default calling convention is `Winapi` on desktop windows;  but your function is declared as `extern C`.

Comment: This solution also applies to `FORTRAN` with the same issue. Just issue a `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES C:: myproc`.

Answer (score 3):

Your [DllImport] declaration is missing the CallingConvention.  Required, your Test function is Cdecl since you didn't use the __stdcall keyword.  The difference between __cdecl and __stdcall is the way the stack gets cleaned up after the call.  __cdecl is the default for most C++ compilers, including Microsoft's.  To fix it on the C++ side, you'd declare it like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
void __stdcall Test( int foo);
```